# How to launch "Google Translate" app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I would like to launch "Google Translate" application when user taps a button in my app.

is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url scheme for google translate is 
googletranslate://

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what url scheme supported by the google translate app but you can open the iTranslate app using this -

To launch the application:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"itranslate://";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

To translate a text:

```
NSString *textToTranslate = @"Hello world"; // Text must be URL-encoded...!
textToTranslate = [textToTranslate stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *test =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itranslate://translate?from=en&to=de&text=%@",textToTranslate];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:test];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

also have a look on this - http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Comment: thanks. so i need to know the url scheme of Google Translate first.